# UICollection View scrollable year view: performance issue

Tags: objective-c, performance, uicollectionview

I am currently dealing with an issue which is bothering me a lot. I am devoloping an endless scrollable year view, which is pretty similar to the standard apple calendar app:

[image]

So I basically have 2 arrays, the first one contains the corresponding weekday of the first day of month, the second one holds the total days of the month I want to display.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    int currentYearIndex = (int)indexPath.section * 12;

    int fillDays      = [[self.dayIndexThisMonthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row  + currentYearIndex ]intValue];
    int daysThisMonth = [[self.daysThisMonthArray     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row  + currentYearIndex ]intValue];

    EMYearCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YearCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureForNumberOfFillDays: fillDays daysThisMonth: daysThisMonth];

    return cell;

}
```

I created a custom UICollectionView class, which receives the aford-said 2 informations and takes care after the creation of the corresponding month:

```
#import "EMYearCell.h"

@interface EMYearCell()

@end

@implementation EMYearCell


- (void)configureForNumberOfFillDays: (int)fillDays daysThisMonth: (int)daysThisMonth
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        void (^labelingBlock) (int, int, int)= ^(int horizontalSpacingMultiplier, int i,  int fillDayAdjuster){

            self.theLabel = [[EMCalendarLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.initialXCord + i * self.distanceBetweenLabels, self.initialYCord + self.horizontalSpacing * horizontalSpacingMultiplier, 50, 50)];
            [self.theLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i + fillDayAdjuster - fillDays]];
            [self addSubview:self.theLabel];
        };

    for (int i = fillDays; i < 7; i++){

        labelingBlock (1,i,1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

        labelingBlock (2,i,8);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

        labelingBlock (3,i,15);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

        labelingBlock (4,i,22);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

        if (i + 29 - fillDays < daysThisMonth + 1){

            labelingBlock (5,i,29);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

        if (i + 36 - fillDays < daysThisMonth + 1){

                labelingBlock (6,i,36);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Despite the fact that I am just adding a bunch of labels as subviews to my custom UICollectionView cell, scrolling is painfully slow and jerky. I really can not think of any possibility to make all this less expensive.

I tried out this:

```
[self.view.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
[self.view.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
```

But I did not notice any improvement either.

I am very thankful in advance for any advice which could help me out in this situation.

Comment: Have you done some performance profiling?

Comment: Yes, i used the time profiler. The following method is marked as red and labeled with "100%":
    EMYearCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YearCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: Is the cell in an XIB? What does it do on reuse? When it's reused are the labels all removed and readied?

Comment: the corresponding view controller in my storyboard contains an collection view, which contains my custom UICollectionView cell. Basically I just remove the colored "today's date" indicator on reuse, because I only want it to be shown in one year.

- (void)prepareForReuse{
    
    for (UIView* theView in self.subviews){
        if (theView.tag == 200){
            [theView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    [super prepareForReuse];
}

Comment: My experience is, configure cells asynchronously in `collectionView :cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and avoid using Auto Layout in cells.

Comment: Yes, auto layout in collection view cells slows down everything, that's why I added those labels as subviews. How would you configure those cells async in this case?

Comment: You shouldn't add those labels as subviews to your cell every time when the cell is reused. Setup the view hierarchy once in the initiailzer, and reset their status in `prepareForReuse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do something like this:

```
@interface EMYearCell : UICollectionViewCell    
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperation *updateOperation;
@end

@interface MyCollectionViewController ()
@property NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];        
    self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        EMYearCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"YearCell" forIndexPath: indexPath];

        // Increment the cell's tag
        NSInteger currentTag = cell.tag + 1;
        cell.tag = currentTag;

        NSBlockOperation *updateOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

                // preparing data for the cell here

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        // Only update the cell if the cell tag hasn't changed. Otherwise, the cell has been re-used.
                        if (cell.tag == currentTag) {

                                // update the cell here

                        }
                });
        }];

        cell.updateOperation = updateOperation;
        [self.operationQueue addOperation:updateOperation];

        return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // cancel the associated update operation
        EMYearCell *yearCell = (EMYearCell *)cell;
        [yearCell.updateOperation cancel];
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, running smooth as silk now! you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

I replaced all labels within my custom `UICollectionViewCell` by adding a `CATextLayer` as a sublayer, et voilà, suddenly scrolling is silky smooth.